# how to close mdiparent form from a dialogue form (like license form)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to close my main form if the user clicks on the exit button on license form or close it.

I try this code on exit button but didn't work:

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 aa=new Form1();
        aa.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

I'll be thankful if somebody can help me!

Comment: Use Environment.Exit() to ensure a program exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that Parent form is the Main form in your application then you can use

```
Application.Exit();
```

To know more [go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).